# using the map operator in angular 4 for object assignment

Tags: angular, highcharts

I need to map one object to another using an array. How do I achieve that in angular 4. Currently I am using a forEach loop to push items to the array. I need to use the map instead.

```
     export interface GraphConfiguration  {

            seriesName: string;
            color: string;
        }
        export interface StressTestAnalysis extends GraphConfiguration {

            curlevel: number;
            decrease: number;
            increase: number;
            yaxis: number[];
            data: number[];
        }

        public results: Array<StressTestAnalysis> = [];
        private _stressResults: Array<StressTestAnalysis> = [];

         @Input() set stressResults(value: Array<StressTestAnalysis>) {
            this._stressResults = value;
            this.addSeries();
            let minY = Math.min(...this.yAxisSeries.map(el => Math.min(...el.yaxis)));
            let maxY = Math.max(...this.yAxisSeries.map(el => Math.max(...el.yaxis)));
    this.generateYAxisArray(minY, maxY);
         }

            this.results.forEach(element => {
                  if (element.data !== null)
                    this.chartSeries.push({ data: element.data, name: element.seriesName, color: element.color });
                   if (element.yaxis !== null)
                    this.yAxisSeries.push({ yaxis: element.yaxis });
                });

private addSeries() {
    if (this._stressResults === null) {
      return;
    }

 private generateYAxisArray(min: any, max: any) {
    let count = min;
    for (count = min; count <= max; count = count + 500000) {
      this.yAxisData.push(count);
    }
  }
```

i am trying to achieve the following. Please note that results should contain the chartseries and yaxisseries. I am looking at removing the foreach loop as i think it is causing duplication.

```
 this.results =  this._stressResults.map((result: any) => {

   return;
    });
```

Histogram component code

```
  <div *ngIf="!showTable" class="tab-pane base-strategy-chart fade show active" id="base-strategy-chart--nva" role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="chart-tab">
          <div class="tb-container">

            <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
              <div class="tb-cell col-12 pt-5">
               <splinechart [series]="chartSeries" [yaxisdata]="yAxisData">
               </splinechart>
                </div>

            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: What are chartSeries and yAxisSeries? Does `map` has to return this?

Comment: Yes the spline chart component expects these two objects. I have updated the post to show how the binding has been done . See the line of code  <splinechart [series]="chartSeries" [yaxisdata]="yAxisData">

Comment: I think my solution will return the results object and i could do <splinechart [series]="result.chartSeries" [yaxisdata]="result.yAxisData">

Comment: You can use this `var result = this.result.reduce((r,o) => {
  if(o.data)
    r.chartSeries.push({data: o.data, name: o.seriesName, color: o.color});
  if(o.yaxis)
    r.yAxisSeries.push({yaxis: o.yaxis});
  return r;
},{chartSeries: [], yAxisSeries: []})`

Comment: I am getting the following error                            
 compiler.es5.js:14985 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at SplineChartComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/shared/Highcharts/spline/spline-

Comment: There is some issue with the method above or the binding. This is how the binding is   <splinechart [series]="chartSeries" [yaxisdata]="yAxisData"> . Do I need to change it to   <splinechart [series]="results.chartSeries" [yaxisdata]="results.yAxisData">

Comment: Cant i return the result to this.results but the return type has to be of type StressTestAnalysis

Comment: If you see above there is already an object above  public results: Array<StressTestAnalysis> = []; How do I assign to this object results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    var numbers = [1, 4, 9];
    this.results =  this.numbers.map((result) => {
           console.log('Your result:', result);
           // Add your business logic to modify result
           new_result = result + 1
           return new_result;
    });
    console.log('Your final results array:', this.results);
```

Comment: Please note that my results object should contain both objects chartseries and yaxisarray